# Usage of ‘on’ with comparison

Tags: word-usage

I had two pens yesterday, and I have three pens today. Is it fine to say ‘I lost a pen yesterday on today’ instead of saying ‘I got a pen today on yesterday’?

Comment: I wouldn't even be sure what you were saying.

Comment: "I have gained a pen since yesterday." You didn't lose one at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not OK. I do not know where you got the use of on today or on yesterday to be used in this context, however it is incorrect.

> On Monday I had a pen, by Tuesday I had lost it.

The important information being "*we have lost a pen*". The sentence is written in the order of events happening.

---

> Yesterday I had two pens, today I have three pens.

*This sentence focuses on what happened each day*

> "I had two pens yesterday, and I have three pens today".

*This sentence is more concerned with how many pens we have than when we had
them.*

---

> I have one less pen than yesterday,

**We do not say** **"I lost a pen yesterday on today"*

*It is not necessary to say today we are referring to yesterday so we must be talking at the present time (today).

**Note** we could say just the opposite in this form *"I have one more pen than yesterday*",

---

> I have another pen today

**We do not say** *"I got a pen today on yesterday?"*

Here we are saying we have one more pen (another) today, we know that we are comparing to what we had before (yesterday), so we do not need to mention yesterday.

**Note** we could say just the opposite in this form *"I have a pen less, today"

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your sentences are correct. No preposition is used with "today", "yesterday" or "tomorrow"; those are [adverbs](https://www.answers.com/Q/What_part_of_speech_is_yesterday) modifying the verb, "have".

One could say, "I had two pens **on Wednesday**, and I have three pens now, **on Thursday**." "On Wednesday," and "on Thursday," are [prepositional phrases](https://blog.prepscholar.com/what-is-a-prepositional-phrase-examples), with a preposition and a noun, the day's name.